# How to change banner ad to adaptive banner in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, admob, flutter-dependencies

i have a flutter app with a banner ad. please how do i adjust the code so my banner ad that appears at the bottom of the screen becomes an adaptive banner that stretches to the edges of the screen horizontally no matter the screen size.

here is my code below

```
class CustomBannerAd extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomBannerAd({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomBannerAd> createState() => _CustomBannerAdState();
}

class _CustomBannerAdState extends State<CustomBannerAd> {
  BannerAd bannerAd;
  bool isBannerAdLoaded = false;
  static String get bannerAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "";
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return "";
    } else {
      throw new UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
    }
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    bannerAd = BannerAd(
      size: AdSize.banner,
      adUnitId: bannerAdUnitId,
      listener: BannerAdListener(onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
        print("Ad Failed to Load");
        ad.dispose();
      }, onAdLoaded: (ad) {
        print("Ad Loaded");
        setState(() {
          isBannerAdLoaded = true;
        });
      }),
      request: const AdRequest(),
    );
    bannerAd.load();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isBannerAdLoaded
        ? SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 50,
            child: AdWidget(
              ad: bannerAd,
            ),
          )
        : SizedBox();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the firststep you have to calculate the sizein which the ad should be displayed. Then in the request this size has to be passed like

```dart
Future<void> _loadAd() async {
    // Get an AnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize before loading the ad.
    final AnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize? size =
        await AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.truncate());

    if (size == null) {
      print('Unable to get height of anchored banner.');
      return;
    }

    _anchoredAdaptiveAd = BannerAd(
      // TODO: replace these test ad units with your own ad unit.
      adUnitId: Platform.isAndroid
          ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111'
          : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716',
      size: size,
      request: AdRequest(),
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          print('$ad loaded: ${ad.responseInfo}');
          setState(() {
            // When the ad is loaded, get the ad size and use it to set
            // the height of the ad container.
            _anchoredAdaptiveAd = ad as BannerAd;
            _isLoaded = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          print('Anchored adaptive banner failedToLoad: $error');
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    );
    return _anchoredAdaptiveAd!.load();
  }
```